# How to split a large table from column

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I'd like to split a table into two (or more) parts. For example, the first should contain the columns `Variable`, `Cluster 0` until `Cluster 3`. Second, `Variable`, `Cluster 4` until `Cluster 7`. Third, `Variable`, `Cluster 8` until `Cluster 10`. I tried to rotate to use `longtable`, `longtable + rotating` and `longtable + lscape`. But I din't have success.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!htp]
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{llllllllllll}
\hline
Variable & Cluster 0 & Cluster 1 & Cluster 2 & Cluster 3 & Cluster 4 & Cluster 5 & Cluster 6 & Cluster 7 & Cluster 8 & Cluster 9 & Cluster 10 \\
\hline
A1            & (41.92, 17.04) & (48.38, 17.46)     & (45.74, 16.68)   & (38.50, 17.39)      & (23.61, 12.38)  & (35.48, 16.78)   & (30.95, 15.41)   & (22.55, 10.55)   & (30.0, 12.78)       & (27.46, 13.68)   & (47.00, 22.46)    \\
A2               &  (3.63, 2.45)     & (4.04, 1.78)       & (4.18, 2.15)     & (3.40, 2.18)      & (2.00, 1.00)      & (2.91, 1.68)     & (2.33, 1.22)       & (1.85, 0.84)    & (2.80, 1.48)     & (2.09, 0.98)       & (2.33, 1.17)    \\
A3            & (81.88, 25.13) & (83.78, 25.14)     & (80.75, 25.19)    & (79.04, 25.85)  & (62.60, 22.44)  & (77.67, 25.52)   & (70.62, 23.89)      & (63.15, 20.90)  & (78.12, 25.48)   & (61.12, 20.90)   & (75.13, 28.74)  \\
A4     &    (16.95, 5.80) & (16.80, 5.39)       & (17.22, 5.79)     & (16.65, 5.82)      & (15.60, 6.39)     & (16.17, 5.95)      & (15.70, 6.21)        & (15.08, 6.50)     & (16.86, 5.87)      & (15.25, 6.38)    & (19.44, 6.05)   \\
A5 &    (5.58, 1.97)    & (6.00, 2.03)          & (5.73, 2.00)      & (5.56, 2.08)   & (4.28, 1.67)      & (5.35, 1.97)       & (4.80, 1.85)         & (4.19, 1.72)      & (5.43, 1.97)       & (4.12, 1.69)       & (5.33, 1.87)    \\
A6                 &    (15.78, 8.20) & (19.89, 8.91)       & (17.29, 8.44)    & (15.32, 7.33)   & (19.27, 9.38)     & (14.52, 7.73)      & (21.49, 10.06)     & (17.16, 7.81)   & (13.23, 6.26)      & (24.39, 11.45)   & (23.75  , 11.79)    \\
A7               &  (6.32, 4.11)    & (8.09, 5.20)        & (6.90, 4.70)     & (5.46, 4.25)      & (1.32, 3.07)    & (4.65, 4.13)     & (3.10, 3.86)         & (0.79, 1.97)      & (3.91, 3.52)       & (1.40, 3.00)     & (5.58, 5.52)    \\
A7               &  (1079.21, 341.87) & (1337.00, 321.09) & (1188.32, 343.02) & (969.69, 336.70)& (623.15, 308.64)& (877.80, 334.12) &  (795.28, 365.01)     & (529.28, 257.37)& (744.72, 247.16) & (688.08, 336.96) & (1018.33, 565.19)\\
A8           &  (0.08, 0.09)  & (0.08, 0.08)        & (0.08, 0.08)     & (0.08, 0.09)    & (0.07, 0.12)      & (0.08, 0.10)       & (0.07, 0.11)         & (0.05, 0.14)      & (0.08, 0.10)       & (0.06, 0.12)       & (0.07, 0.10)    \\
A9       &  (0.45, 0.10)   & (0.43, 0.09)        & (0.45, 0.10)       & (0.43, 0.12)     & (0.42, 0.16)      & (0.43, 0.13)       & (0.42, 0.14)         & (0.40, 0.18)      & (0.43, 0.13)       & (0.42, 0.15)       & (0.40, 0.14)      \\
A10        &    (29.06, 11.90) & (29.16, 10.90)     & (27.62, 11.38)    & (29.37, 12.40)  & (33.81, 15.23)  & (30.50, 12.91)      & (32.39, 13.92)   & (34.34, 16.45)  & (30.34, 13.30)       & (33.07, 15.36)    & (29.39, 16.36)  \\
A11    &    (48.68, 14.17)  & (60.30, 13.92)       & (54.95, 14.92)    & (43.46, 14.03)  & (25.32, 10.88)  & (39.13, 13.50)   & (34.31, 13.88)   & (21.65, 9.36)     & (34.72, 11.29)   & (27.94, 11.91)   & (45.27, 25.48)  \\
A12     &   (281.04, 89.12)& (347.93, 82.88)    & (308.74, 88.32)  & (253.14, 86.95) & (159.23, 76.27) & (228.18, 85.93)   & (204.00, 92.58)     & (134.84, 63.06) &(195.90, 63.75)   & (175.90, 83.24)    & (265.06, 141.55)\\
A13      &  (157.10, 50.13)  & (198.93, 48.32)    & (171.46, 49.63)  & (142.32, 50.97)  & (92.37, 45.85)  & (129.00, 49.12)       & (117.86, 54.80)      & (79.01, 37.84)  &(110.36, 36.47)   & (102.27, 49.94)  & (148.50, 84.43)   \\
A14     &   (6.43, 2.16)   & (7.94, 2.20)        & (7.01, 2.12)      & (5.86, 2.13)    & (3.84, 1.82)    & (5.37, 2.03)       & (4.84, 2.17)       & (3.36, 1.60)    & (4.78, 1.65)       & (4.14, 1.93)       & (5.83, 2.72)    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:persona}
\end{table}
```

*Obs.:* In `longtable` environment, I used the code below, but it broke the lines not the columns.

```
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 5} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{7}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 10} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
```

Comment: Why don't you split it manually?

Comment: Because I will have two tables with different enumerations.

Comment: What does your last comment mean? You can manually split your table in as many parts as you like while still assigning a single caption.

Comment: I need a unique caption. For example, `Table 1. Some caption`, `Table 1. (continuation)` etc.

Comment: Is it intentional, that variable "A7"  exists twice in your table?

Comment: It isn't; this is an error. But your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

{\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{lllll}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:persona}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Caption -- continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
Variable & Cluster 0     & Cluster 1         & Cluster 2         & Cluster 3        \\
\midrule
A1   & (41.92, 17.04)    & (48.38, 17.46)    & (45.74, 16.68)    & (38.50, 17.39)   \\
A2   & (3.63, 2.45)      & (4.04, 1.78)      & (4.18, 2.15)      & (3.40, 2.18)     \\
A3   & (81.88, 25.13)    & (83.78, 25.14)    & (80.75, 25.19)    & (79.04, 25.85)   \\ \addlinespace
A4   & (16.95, 5.80)     & (16.80, 5.39)     & (17.22, 5.79)     & (16.65, 5.82)    \\
A5   & (5.58, 1.97)      & (6.00, 2.03)      & (5.73, 2.00)      & (5.56, 2.08)     \\ 
A6   & (15.78, 8.20)     & (19.89, 8.91)     & (17.29, 8.44)     & (15.32, 7.33)    \\  \addlinespace
A7   & (6.32, 4.11)      & (8.09, 5.20)      & (6.90, 4.70)      & (5.46, 4.25)     \\
A7   & (1079.21, 341.87) & (1337.00, 321.09) & (1188.32, 343.02) & (969.69, 336.70) \\
A8   & (0.08, 0.09)      & (0.08, 0.08)      & (0.08, 0.08)      & (0.08, 0.09)     \\ \addlinespace
A9   & (0.45, 0.10)      & (0.43, 0.09)      & (0.45, 0.10)      & (0.43, 0.12)     \\
A10  & (29.06, 11.90)    & (29.16, 10.90)    & (27.62, 11.38)    & (29.37, 12.40)   \\ 
A11  & (48.68, 14.17)    & (60.30, 13.92)    & (54.95, 14.92)    & (43.46, 14.03)   \\ \addlinespace
A12  & (281.04, 89.12)   & (347.93, 82.88)   & (308.74, 88.32)   & (253.14, 86.95)  \\
A13  & (157.10, 50.13)   & (198.93, 48.32)   & (171.46, 49.63)   & (142.32, 50.97)  \\
A14  & (6.43, 2.16)      & (7.94, 2.20)      & (7.01, 2.12)      & (5.86, 2.13)     \\ 
\midrule
Variable & Cluster 4     & Cluster 5         & Cluster 6         & Cluster 7 \\
\midrule
A1  & (23.61, 12.38)     & (35.48, 16.78)    & (30.95, 15.41)    & (22.55, 10.55)    \\
A2  & (2.00, 1.00)       & (2.91, 1.68)      & (2.33, 1.22)      & (1.85, 0.84)      \\
A3  & (62.60, 22.44)     & (77.67, 25.52)    & (70.62, 23.89)    & (63.15, 20.90)    \\ \addlinespace
A4  & (15.60, 6.39)      & (16.17, 5.95)     & (15.70, 6.21)     & (15.08, 6.50)     \\
A5  & (4.28, 1.67)       & (5.35, 1.97)      & (4.80, 1.85)      & (4.19, 1.72)      \\ 
A6  & (19.27, 9.38)      & (14.52, 7.73)     & (21.49, 10.06)    & (17.16, 7.81)     \\ \addlinespace
A7  & (1.32, 3.07)       & (4.65, 4.13)      & (3.10, 3.86)      & (0.79, 1.97)      \\
A7  & (623.15, 308.64)   & (877.80, 334.12)  & (795.28, 365.01)  & (529.28, 257.37)  \\
A8  & (0.07, 0.12)       & (0.08, 0.10)      & (0.07, 0.11)      & (0.05, 0.14)      \\ \addlinespace
A9  & (0.42, 0.16)       & (0.43, 0.13)      & (0.42, 0.14)      & (0.40, 0.18)      \\
A10 & (33.81, 15.23)     & (30.50, 12.91)    & (32.39, 13.92)    & (34.34, 16.45)    \\ 
A11 & (25.32, 10.88)     & (39.13, 13.50)    & (34.31, 13.88)    & (21.65, 9.36)     \\ \addlinespace
A12 & (159.23, 76.27)    & (228.18, 85.93)   & (204.00, 92.58)   & (134.84, 63.06)   \\
A13 & (92.37, 45.85)     & (129.00, 49.12)   & (117.86, 54.80)   & (79.01, 37.84)    \\
A14 & (3.84, 1.82)       & (5.37, 2.03)      & (4.84, 2.17)      & (3.36, 1.60)      \\ 
\midrule
Variable & Cluster 8     & Cluster 9         & Cluster 10 \\
\midrule
A1  & (30.0, 12.78)      & (27.46, 13.68)    & (47.00, 22.46)    \\
A2  & (2.80, 1.48)       & (2.09, 0.98)      & (2.33, 1.17)      \\
A3  & (78.12, 25.48)     & (61.12, 20.90)    & (75.13, 28.74)    \\ \addlinespace
A4  & (16.86, 5.87)      & (15.25, 6.38)     & (19.44, 6.05)     \\
A5  & (5.43, 1.97)       & (4.12, 1.69)      & (5.33, 1.87)      \\ 
A6  & (13.23, 6.26)      & (24.39, 11.45)    & (23.75  , 11.79)  \\ \addlinespace
A7  & (3.91, 3.52)       & (1.40, 3.00)      & (5.58, 5.52)      \\
A7  & (744.72, 247.16)   & (688.08, 336.96)  & (1018.33, 565.19) \\
A8  & (0.08, 0.10)       & (0.06, 0.12)      & (0.07, 0.10)      \\ \addlinespace
A9  & (0.43, 0.13)       & (0.42, 0.15)      & (0.40, 0.14)      \\
A10 & (30.34, 13.30)     & (33.07, 15.36)    & (29.39, 16.36)    \\ 
A11 & (34.72, 11.29)     & (27.94, 11.91)    & (45.27, 25.48)    \\ \addlinespace
A12 & (195.90, 63.75)    & (175.90, 83.24)   & (265.06, 141.55)  \\
A13 & (110.36, 36.47)    & (102.27, 49.94)   & (148.50, 84.43)   \\
A14 & (4.78, 1.65)       & (4.14, 1.93)      & (5.83, 2.72)      \\
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clearly what I was talking about ;)

Answer (score 9):

The opening and closing parentheses and the spaces after the commas in all data cells actually take up *a lot of space*. If you're willing to suppress them, it's entirely possible to typeset the table in a single landscape-oriented page.

The following code and screenshot presents two possible solutions. The first pretty much follows the OP's code in terms of layout, such as left-alignment of all columns. The second centers the data columns on the commas, provides more structure to the header, and arranges for some visual grouping by inserting extra whitespace after every third data row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,caption,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D,,{-1}} % for second table
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{l} }
\toprule
Var. 
& Cluster 0 & Cluster 1 & Cluster 2 & Cluster 3 & Cluster 4 
& Cluster 5 & Cluster 6 & Cluster 7 & Cluster 8 & Cluster 9 
& Cluster 10 \\
\midrule
A1 & 41.92,17.04 & 48.38,17.46 & 45.74,16.68 & 38.50,17.39 & 23.61,12.38 & 35.48,16.78 & 30.95,15.41 & 22.55,10.55 & 30.0,12.78 & 27.46,13.68 & 47.00,22.46 \\
A2 & 3.63,2.45 & 4.04,1.78 & 4.18,2.15 & 3.40,2.18 & 2.00,1.00 & 2.91,1.68 & 2.33,1.22 & 1.85,0.84 & 2.80,1.48 & 2.09,0.98 & 2.33,1.17 \\
A3 & 81.88,25.13 & 83.78,25.14 & 80.75,25.19 & 79.04,25.85 & 62.60,22.44 & 77.67,25.52 & 70.62,23.89 & 63.15,20.90 & 78.12,25.48 & 61.12,20.90 & 75.13,28.74 \\
\addlinespace
A4 & 16.95,5.80 & 16.80,5.39 & 17.22,5.79 & 16.65,5.82 & 15.60,6.39 & 16.17,5.95 & 15.70,6.21 & 15.08,6.50 & 16.86,5.87 & 15.25,6.38 & 19.44,6.05 \\
A5 & 5.58,1.97 & 6.00,2.03 & 5.73,2.00 & 5.56,2.08 & 4.28,1.67 & 5.35,1.97 & 4.80,1.85 & 4.19,1.72 & 5.43,1.97 & 4.12,1.69 & 5.33,1.87 \\
A6 & 15.78,8.20 & 19.89,8.91 & 17.29,8.44 & 15.32,7.33 & 19.27,9.38 & 14.52,7.73 & 21.49,10.06 & 17.16,7.81 & 13.23,6.26 & 24.39,11.45 & 23.75 ,11.79 \\
A7 & 6.32,4.11 & 8.09,5.20 & 6.90,4.70 & 5.46,4.25 & 1.32,3.07 & 4.65,4.13 & 3.10,3.86 & 0.79,1.97 & 3.91,3.52 & 1.40,3.00 & 5.58,5.52 \\
A7 & 1079.21,341.87 & 1337.00,321.09 & 1188.32,343.02 & 969.69,336.70& 623.15,308.64& 877.80,334.12 & 795.28,365.01 & 529.28,257.37& 744.72,247.16 & 688.08,336.96 & 1018.33,565.19\\
A8 & 0.08,0.09 & 0.08,0.08 & 0.08,0.08 & 0.08,0.09 & 0.07,0.12 & 0.08,0.10 & 0.07,0.11 & 0.05,0.14 & 0.08,0.10 & 0.06,0.12 & 0.07,0.10 \\
A9 & 0.45,0.10 & 0.43,0.09 & 0.45,0.10 & 0.43,0.12 & 0.42,0.16 & 0.43,0.13 & 0.42,0.14 & 0.40,0.18 & 0.43,0.13 & 0.42,0.15 & 0.40,0.14 \\
A10 & 29.06,11.90 & 29.16,10.90 & 27.62,11.38 & 29.37,12.40 & 33.81,15.23 & 30.50,12.91 & 32.39,13.92 & 34.34,16.45 & 30.34,13.30 & 33.07,15.36 & 29.39,16.36 \\
A11 & 48.68,14.17 & 60.30,13.92 & 54.95,14.92 & 43.46,14.03 & 25.32,10.88 & 39.13,13.50 & 34.31,13.88 & 21.65,9.36 & 34.72,11.29 & 27.94,11.91 & 45.27,25.48 \\
A12 & 281.04,89.12& 347.93,82.88 & 308.74,88.32 & 253.14,86.95 & 159.23,76.27 & 228.18,85.93 & 204.00,92.58 & 134.84,63.06 &195.90,63.75 & 175.90,83.24 & 265.06,141.55\\
A13 & 157.10,50.13 & 198.93,48.32 & 171.46,49.63 & 142.32,50.97 & 92.37,45.85 & 129.00,49.12 & 117.86,54.80 & 79.01,37.84 &110.36,36.47 & 102.27,49.94 & 148.50,84.43 \\
A14 & 6.43,2.16 & 7.94,2.20 & 7.01,2.12 & 5.86,2.13 & 3.84,1.82 & 5.37,2.03 & 4.84,2.17 & 3.36,1.60 & 4.78,1.65 & 4.14,1.93 & 5.83,2.72 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:persona}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{11}{d} }
\toprule
Var. & \multicolumn{11}{c}{Clusters} \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
 & \mc{0} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} & \mc{5} & \mc{6} & \mc{7} & \mc{8} & \mc{9} & \mc{10} \\
\midrule
A1 & 41.92,17.04 & 48.38,17.46 & 45.74,16.68 & 38.50,17.39 & 23.61,12.38 & 35.48,16.78 & 30.95,15.41 & 22.55,10.55 & 30.0,12.78 & 27.46,13.68 & 47.00,22.46 \\
A2 & 3.63,2.45 & 4.04,1.78 & 4.18,2.15 & 3.40,2.18 & 2.00,1.00 & 2.91,1.68 & 2.33,1.22 & 1.85,0.84 & 2.80,1.48 & 2.09,0.98 & 2.33,1.17 \\
A3 & 81.88,25.13 & 83.78,25.14 & 80.75,25.19 & 79.04,25.85 & 62.60,22.44 & 77.67,25.52 & 70.62,23.89 & 63.15,20.90 & 78.12,25.48 & 61.12,20.90 & 75.13,28.74 \\
\addlinespace
A4 & 16.95,5.80 & 16.80,5.39 & 17.22,5.79 & 16.65,5.82 & 15.60,6.39 & 16.17,5.95 & 15.70,6.21 & 15.08,6.50 & 16.86,5.87 & 15.25,6.38 & 19.44,6.05 \\
A5 & 5.58,1.97 & 6.00,2.03 & 5.73,2.00 & 5.56,2.08 & 4.28,1.67 & 5.35,1.97 & 4.80,1.85 & 4.19,1.72 & 5.43,1.97 & 4.12,1.69 & 5.33,1.87 \\
A6 & 15.78,8.20 & 19.89,8.91 & 17.29,8.44 & 15.32,7.33 & 19.27,9.38 & 14.52,7.73 & 21.49,10.06 & 17.16,7.81 & 13.23,6.26 & 24.39,11.45 & 23.75 ,11.79 \\ 
\addlinespace
A7 & 6.32,4.11 & 8.09,5.20 & 6.90,4.70 & 5.46,4.25 & 1.32,3.07 & 4.65,4.13 & 3.10,3.86 & 0.79,1.97 & 3.91,3.52 & 1.40,3.00 & 5.58,5.52 \\
A7 & 1079.21,341.87 & 1337.00,321.09 & 1188.32,343.02 & 969.69,336.70& 623.15,308.64& 877.80,334.12 & 795.28,365.01 & 529.28,257.37& 744.72,247.16 & 688.08,336.96 & 1018.33,565.19\\
A8 & 0.08,0.09 & 0.08,0.08 & 0.08,0.08 & 0.08,0.09 & 0.07,0.12 & 0.08,0.10 & 0.07,0.11 & 0.05,0.14 & 0.08,0.10 & 0.06,0.12 & 0.07,0.10 \\
\addlinespace
A9 & 0.45,0.10 & 0.43,0.09 & 0.45,0.10 & 0.43,0.12 & 0.42,0.16 & 0.43,0.13 & 0.42,0.14 & 0.40,0.18 & 0.43,0.13 & 0.42,0.15 & 0.40,0.14 \\
A10 & 29.06,11.90 & 29.16,10.90 & 27.62,11.38 & 29.37,12.40 & 33.81,15.23 & 30.50,12.91 & 32.39,13.92 & 34.34,16.45 & 30.34,13.30 & 33.07,15.36 & 29.39,16.36 \\
A11 & 48.68,14.17 & 60.30,13.92 & 54.95,14.92 & 43.46,14.03 & 25.32,10.88 & 39.13,13.50 & 34.31,13.88 & 21.65,9.36 & 34.72,11.29 & 27.94,11.91 & 45.27,25.48 \\
\addlinespace
A12 & 281.04,89.12& 347.93,82.88 & 308.74,88.32 & 253.14,86.95 & 159.23,76.27 & 228.18,85.93 & 204.00,92.58 & 134.84,63.06 &195.90,63.75 & 175.90,83.24 & 265.06,141.55\\
A13 & 157.10,50.13 & 198.93,48.32 & 171.46,49.63 & 142.32,50.97 & 92.37,45.85 & 129.00,49.12 & 117.86,54.80 & 79.01,37.84 &110.36,36.47 & 102.27,49.94 & 148.50,84.43 \\
A14 & 6.43,2.16 & 7.94,2.20 & 7.01,2.12 & 5.86,2.13 & 3.84,1.82 & 5.37,2.03 & 4.84,2.17 & 3.36,1.60 & 4.78,1.65 & 4.14,1.93 & 5.83,2.72 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Same table, except (ii) more structure inside header, (ii) data columns centered on commas, and (iii) extra whitespace every third row}
\label{tab:take2}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: congratulations on 400k !!

Comment: @jsbibra - Many thanks! Very much appreciated. Actually, still 426 points to go until it's entirely official...

Comment: +1 to get closer to the official 400k :)

Comment: What does `{-1}` in `\newcolumntype{d}{D,,{-1}}` do? I assume this is (somehow) responsible for centering the commas?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Your assumption is perfectly on target. For more information on this subject, see the explanations at the bottom of p. 1 of the package's  user guide. Type `texdoc dcolumn` in a command window to open the user guide in a pdf browser.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that package in the preamble, my bad.